# Swift: Как скрыть и показать UI элементы на экране

Tags: swift

Здравствуйте я начинающий программист и познаю науку можно сказать своими силами)))
Задача такая:
Есть элементы на экране при запуске приложения и они должны быть все время скрыты.
Есть переменная значение которой увеличивается и при достижении определенного значения этой переменной, вышесказанный элемент должен от обратиться на экране ровно на 5 секунд а за тем сново стать скрытым.
Помогите пожалуйста как это можно реализовать?

Comment: уточните пожалуйста что именно не понятно? как вариант - сделайте через UIStackView, чтобы все было аккуратно уложено, дальше запускайте ваш алгоритм, и в определенный момент показывайте по таймеру нужные вам вьюхи

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь! Я решил свою задачу несколько иначе!

Answer (score 0):

И так...сеть переменная, которая достигает определенного значения и при выполнении этого условия на экране смартфона появляется надпись, так как в коде ее атрибуту видимости на экране, присваевается значение:

viewLabel.isHidden = false

и для того что бы эта надпись исчезла после прошествия 5 секунд я использовал отложенный метод:

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5)
{self.viewLabel.isHidden = true}

Тем самым добился необходимого мне результата)))